# How do I get all errors and not only the first in snowflake copy command?

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to get all errors from copy into command in snowflake.

this is my command:

```
COPY INTO MY_TABLE
        FROM (SELECT t.$1,t.$2,t.$3,t.$4, t.$5,t.$6)
        FROM @MY_STAGE t)
        file_format = (format_name = MY_FORMAT)
        ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE_20%';
```

now, after thos command executed successfully- I would like to see which records failed.
so- if I am looking at information_schema:

```
SELECT FILE_NAME,ERROR_COUNT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOAD_HISTORY
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
            AND STATUS = 'PARTIALLY_LOADED'
            AND ROW_COUNT - ROW_PARSED <= ERROR_LIMIT
            GROUP BY 1
```

then I get that for file x error_count = 2
but if I run this command:

```
select * from table(validate(MY_TABLE, job_id => '_last'))
```

then I get like 1800 errors, which looked different from each other, looks like real errors.
but this is the same file that I get in information_schema error_count 2.

I need another way to get the 2 errors.

Comment: your question title and your real expectations from body of question do not match; what exactly you want ; you want errors ,history of all errors while loading data into table or you want error specific to query that executed copy command. if you would like to get only 2 errors specific to copy command can this be not useful select * from table(validate(MY_TABLE, job_id => 'queryid'))  instead of select * from table(validate(MY_TABLE, job_id => '_last'))

Comment: @akshindesnowflake thank you. but how do I get the query id of my copy command? I want a stable solution

Comment: @Riki - UUID used for the files is the QueryID of COPY command. 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html